# I need to hash (obfuscate) a column of data in a CSV file. Script preferred

Tags: powershell, csv, scripting, batch-file

I have a pipe-delimited text file with a header row. (I said CSV in the question to make it a a bit more immediately understandable ... I imagine most solutions would be applicable to either format.)

The file looks like this:

```
COLUMN1|COLUMN2|COLUMN3|COLUMN4|...|
Field1|Field2|Field3|Field4|...|
...
```

I need to obscure the data in (for example) columns 3 and 9, without affecting any of the other entries in the file.

I want to do this using a hashing algorithm like SHA1 or MD5, so that the same strings will resove to the same hash values anywhere they are encountered.

**EDIT - Why I want to do this**
I need to send some data to a third party, and certain columns contain sensitive information (e.g. customer names). I need the file to be complete, and where a string is replaced, I need it to be done in the same way every time it is encountered (so that any mapping or grouping remains). It does not need military encryption, just to be difficult to reverse. As I need to to this intermittently, a scripted solution would be ideal.
**/EDIT**

What is the easiest way to achieve this using a command line tool or script?

By preference, I would like a batch script or PowerShell script, since that does not require any additional software to achieve...

Comment: Why do you need to hash the strings, if we can get a overview of what you are trying to accomplish it will be easier to provide a solution that will work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have edited my question to include more detail about what and why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
(Import-Csv .\my.csv -delimiter '|' ) | ForEach-Object{     
    $_.column3 = $_.column3.gethashcode()
    $_.column4 = $_.column4.gethashcode()
    $_    
} | Export-Csv .\myobfuscated.csv -NoTypeInformation -delimiter '|'
```

Comment: Thanks. This is great. I knew there must be a nice way of achieving it!

Answer (score 0):

```
$md5 = new-object -TypeName Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider
$utf8 = new-object -TypeName Text.UTF8Encoding

import-csv original.csv -delimiter '|' |
foreach {   
    $_.Column3 = [BitConverter]::ToString($md5.ComputeHash($utf8.GetBytes($_.Column3)))
    $_.Column9 = [BitConverter]::ToString($md5.ComputeHash($utf8.GetBytes($_.Column9)))
    $_
} |
export-csv encrypted.csv -delimiter '|' -noTypeInformation
```